# save datatable as pdf in google chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, google-visualization

I'm Trying to save table chart as pdf and it's throwing error. Following is my code :

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function getImgData(chartContainer) {
            var chartArea = chartContainer.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0].parentNode;
            var svg = chartArea.innerHTML;
            var chartDoc = chartContainer.ownerDocument;
            var canvas = chartDoc.createElement('canvas');
            canvas.setAttribute('width', (chartArea.offsetWidth * 5));
            canvas.setAttribute('height', (chartArea.offsetHeight * 5));


            canvas.setAttribute(
                'style',
                'position: absolute; ' +
                'top: ' + (-chartArea.offsetHeight * 2) + 'px;' +
                'left: ' + (-chartArea.offsetWidth * 2) + 'px;');
            chartDoc.body.appendChild(canvas);
            canvg(canvas, svg);
            var imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/JPEG');
            doc.addImage(imgData, "JPEG", 10,10, 210,100); 
            canvas.parentNode.removeChild(canvas);
            return imgData;
          }

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#pdfBtn').click(function () {  
            var chartContainer = document.getElementById('table_div');
            var chartDoc = chartContainer.ownerDocument;
            var img = chartDoc.createElement('img');
            img.src = getImgData(chartContainer);
            doc.save('NotionViz.pdf');
        });

    });
</script>
```

Error is :

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of undefined
getImgData
(anonymous function)
jQuery.event.dispatch
elemData.handle

How can i export data table to pdf. Solution is greatly appreciated.

Comment: what kind of error ? please edit your question to include the error

Comment: Hi Raptor, Edited the question. I 've added the error.